# Elasticsearch CORS HTTPD and AngularJs Communication Issue

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, cors

I am using Elasticsearch to store and query logs. I am creating a front end UI that will display the queried information from Elasticsearch to a webpage using AngularJs. The webpage is running on CentOS 6 Apache HTTPD on port 80. Elasticsearch is running on port 9200. When I query Elasticsearch using AngularJs I am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my_ip/ali_viewer/log/_search. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

This seems to be a common issue found on stackoverflow and the rest of the web, but after trying so many solutions with no success I will post my specific configuration.

***httpd.conf***

```
<Directory />
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

***elasticsearch.yml***

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

[More robust handling of CORS HTTP Access Control #16436](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16436)

This is an issue in version 2.3.1, You can use nginx as reverse proxy to solve this problem.